# IllegalArgumentException: file contains path separator

Tags: android

I'm trying to check whether a zip exists in a subdirectory in the application's internal storage:

```
File file = this.getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/thesubdirectory/the.zip";
if(file.exists()) {
    Log.e(this.class.getName(), "file exists");
}
```

This is throwing a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /data/data/my.package.name/files/thesubdirectory/the.zip contains a path separator`.

Why is this happening? I thought this was the way you *should* check whether a file exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

file.exists is.  But getFileStreamPath can't take a path, it needs to take a filename in that directory.  Try this:

```
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/thesubdirectory/the.zip");
```